# Unknown request /cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init from 61.160.213.108

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scanning, cgi-bin

I am using Nginx & Phusion Passenger for running Rails app. I got these errors in the access log:

```
I, [2015-07-11T02:21:16.369230 #12228]  INFO -- : Started GET "/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init" for 61.160.213.56 at 2015-07-11 02:21:16 -0400
F, [2015-07-11T02:21:16.382745 #12228] FATAL -- : ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init"):
```

I tried to search the IP 61.160.213.56 over the google, I found this page: http://www.ipillion.com/ip/61.160.213.108

It said that: 61.160.213.108 is known for firewall alert, port scanning.

Could any one tell me what does it mean? Do I need to block this IP from my site?

Answer (score 3):

It's port scanning, and sending lots of dummy URL which could be allowing attacker to login to Admin page.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen the same ip using the same URL. Here are a few more similar IPS doing the same thing:

```
61.160.213.55
61.160.213.56
61.160.213.247
61.160.213.32
```

Comment: 61.160.213.247 is chinese